# How to find out if Google Plus One button is pressed

Tags: javascript, google-plus-one

I have a web site that displays a table of contents, and I'd like to use the Google Plus One button as a kind of persistent "favourite" marker. So a user would Plus One a page, and then in my table of contents I would show that page as being "Plus Oned" somehow (either bold the entry, show a plus image or something similar).

So is there any way to call the Plus One api to find out if a URL has been "Plus Oned" by the current user?

Note that I don't want to get the plus one count (as shown at http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/) and I don't want to have to  manually intercept plus one clicks and store the details myself.

http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/ may do what I want. The isSetByViewer parameter that is returned is possibly what I want, but simply calling the web service as described in the web page always returns a isSetByViewer value of false. I would assume that some other undocumented data or cookie/header information would have to be sent to the web service identify the current user.

Comment: Using a callback function: `plusone_callback(obj){if(obj.state=="on"){//DO THINGS HERE}}` This will tell you if the state is `on`.

Comment: For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pos.plusones.getSignupState` in the hidden API, which you can try to experiment with instead of `pos.plusones.get`. Other than that, I think you should specify the G+ user id in the userID parameter.

Furthermore, you can try to sniff the network traffic for the +1 button with wireshark, webkit inspector and chrome://net-internals (watch SPDY traffic to client6.google.com). OR you could try to debug the js code with step to find what variable makes the +1 button highlight.